# How to prevent Core NLP Pos Tagger from tokenizing?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I use the the core NLP Parser to tokenize my text. Example "...dem späteren Papst Benedikt XVI., in der Glaubenskongergation..."

Now the problem is, when I use the parser to tokenize my text I get a token with "XVI." which is correct. But when I use this token with the Core NLP Pos Tagger, I get two tokens back [u'XVI', u'NE'], [u'.', u'$.'] which I don't want. Can I somehow restict the tagger to the original tokens?

Answer (score 0):

If you run a pipeline on that text it should tokenize properly.

Here is the sample command:

```
java -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -props StanfordCoreNLP-german.properties -file example-1.txt -outputFormat text
```

You need the full Stanford CoreNLP release to do this, and you need the German models jar.

Those resources are all available here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html

For reference, these are the German properties (which get used when you specify using the German properties file as in the command above):

```
annotators = tokenize, ssplit, pos, ner, parse

tokenize.language = de

pos.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/german/german-hgc.tagger

ner.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/german.conll.hgc_175m_600.crf.ser.gz
ner.applyNumericClassifiers = false
ner.useSUTime = false

parse.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/germanFactored.ser.gz

# depparse
depparse.model    = edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/UD_German.gz
depparse.language = german
```

The command above will create a human readable output file with both the parse tree and all of the pos tags.  There are a variety of ways to run a pipeline.  One is the command line command shown above, you can also run one with the Java API.

More details here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/cmdline.html
and here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html